# Equivalent regex in grep and sed of using not operator (!) in awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

Suppose I want to find a regular expression of this form:

```
awk '!/[^TAP]/ {print $1}' sample.txt
```

which gives matches for ATA, but not for ATAU, TAR and TR.

On the other hand this gives matches for all four of them:

```
awk '/[TAP]/ {print $1}' sample.txt
```

What is the correct regex syntax in `grep` and `sed` for the former case?

Mock input file is:

```
ATA
ATAU
TAR
TR
```

Output should be the line composed by a string containing only characters A and/or T and/or P, but not any other character.

Comment: What are you trying to match? Can you include sample input with expected output?

Comment: Do you REALLY want to find out how to write the equivalent regexps in grep and sed or would you actually like to learn how to idiomatically get the same behavior with grep and sed? Those tools don't ONLY have regexps, they have options too that provide the context within which the regexps are applied so a regexp of `[TAP]`, for example, in a grep or sed command can mean very different things depending on the options provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '/^[ATP]+$/' file

ATA
```

Or this `grep` would also work:

```sh
grep '^[ATP]\+$' file

ATA
```

Regex pattern `^[ATP]+$` will match one or more of `A`, `T` or `P` letters and due to anchors `^` and `$`, it won't allow any other character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/[^TAP]/d' file
```

If there in neither a `T` or an `A` or a `P` delete the line.

or:

```
sed -n '/[^TAP]/!p' file
```

Turn of implicit printing and if the regexp is false, print the line.